# I am unable to start a rails server with the gem sovren installed :undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I started a new rails app my Gem file as below:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
gem 'sovren'
```

I am unsure why i get this error

```
/Users/toad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:56:in `block in require': undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from /Users/toad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:56:in `map!'
from /Users/toad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:56:in `require'
from /Users/toad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
from /Users/toad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sovren-0.0.5/lib/sovren.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/toad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
from /Users/toad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /Users/toad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
from /Users/toad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
from /Users/toad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
from /Users/toad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
from /Users/toad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
from /Users/toad/Code/Ruby/sovren/sovren_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/toad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `require'
from /Users/toad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/toad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
from /Users/toad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I remove gem 'sovren' and it works.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Paste error backtrace.

Comment: i have added it to the question, thanks